# How can I sort this array in PHP based on an array element?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this an array with this form

**CODE PHP:**

```
$mergeArr = array_merge($facebookURL, $twitterURL, $instagramURL, $linkedinURL, $pinterestURL); 

    array (size=15)
      'fbenabled' => string '1' (length=1)
      'fburl' => string 'https://www.facebook.com' (length=24)
      'fborder' => string '4' (length=1)         // order element
      'twenabled' => string '1' (length=1)
      'twurl' => string 'https://www.twiiter.com' (length=23)
      'tworder' => string '7' (length=1)         // order element
      'instaenabled' => string '1' (length=1)
      'instaurl' => string 'https://www.instagram.com' (length=25)
      'instaorder' => string '9' (length=1)      // order element
      'linkenabled' => string '1' (length=1)
      'linkurl' => string 'https://www.linkedin.com' (length=24)
      'linkorder' => string '2' (length=1)       // order element
      'pinenabled' => string '1' (length=1)
      'pinurl' => string 'https://www.pinterest.com' (length=25)
      'pinkorder' => string '1' (length=1)       // order element
```

I want to sort this array according to the `"order"` value of each element.

The new form of the array should be:

```
   array (size=15)
          'pinenabled' => string '1' (length=1)
          'pinurl' => string 'https://www.pinterest.com' (length=25)
          'pinkorder' => string '1' (length=1)       // order element
          'linkenabled' => string '1' (length=1)
          'linkurl' => string 'https://www.linkedin.com' (length=24)
          'linkorder' => string '2' (length=1)       // order element
          'fbenabled' => string '1' (length=1)
          'fburl' => string 'https://www.facebook.com' (length=24)
          'fborder' => string '4' (length=1)         // order element
          'twenabled' => string '1' (length=1)
          'twurl' => string 'https://www.twiiter.com' (length=23)
          'tworder' => string '7' (length=1)         // order element
          'instaenabled' => string '1' (length=1)
          'instaurl' => string 'https://www.instagram.com' (length=25)
          'instaorder' => string '9' (length=1)      // order element
```

Can you help me please order this array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so what specific issues are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be to use [asort](https://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

```
asort($mergeArr);
```

Now that I'm taking a second look at your code I'm noticing that the order you want to achieve is actually incredible difficult to do, you want to group the twitter, instagram and facebook related elements without actually grouping them.

You might want to re-organise your array to look something like this:

```
$mergeArr = array(
    'facebook'  => $facebookURL, 
    'twitter'   => $twitterURL, 
    'instagram' => $instagramURL, 
    'linkedin'  => $linkedinURL, 
    'pintrest'  => $pinterestURL
);

usort($mergeArr, function($a, $b) {

    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];

});
```

In order for this to work, you would need to change the 'order' keys to the word 'order', e.g. change 'pinkorder' to 'order', 'linkorder' to 'order', etc.

Comment: ok but how to organize? I can share it from 3 to 3 but I do not want this because I can have a dynamic number of items.
I can not use a constant, but need to print the array in a dynamic way

Comment: $splitArr = array_chunk($mergeArr, 3); 
for example I can do this, but number 3 is constant, I want something dynamic

Comment: You need to change the structure of your code in order to get this to work, the way it is currently setup is not logical, please see edit above.

Comment: can you please make an example in the "codepen" or somewhere because I do not understand exactly how to apply this code.